# Call Web Service method that insert an object from jquery ajax

Tags: json, web-services, jquery, insert

I have a web service method similiar to this:

```
@Path("/insert_update")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Object insert(User obj) {
  ...(insert and return object)
}
```

And I want to call this method from jquery, using ajax. I've tried something like this:

```
var rootURL = "http://Path/to/my/web/service";

function insertUpdate() {
  var user = {'name' : $("#name").val(),
              'surname' : $("#surname").val(),
              'surname1' : $("#surname1").val(),
              'usertxt' : $("#usertxt").val(),
              'password' : $("#password").val() };
  $.ajax({
         url : rootURL + "/insert_update",
         type : "POST",
         contentType: 'json',
         dataType : "json",
         data : user,
         success : function(data) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         },
         error : function(data) {
         }
  });
}
```

Is this code correct? When I try to use it I get this response:

> Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... . Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I hope you can help me.

Greetings.

UPDATE

The web service is in the same machine, but in other port. I run the web service project on a WebSphere Application Server and then I only open the HTML file to test my code.

I have other method I don't have problem with, like this:

```
@Path("/all")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object all() {
  ...(get all users)
}
```

And the JQuery method for this code:

```
function all() {
$.ajax({
    url : rootURL + "/all",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        $("#tabla tbody:last").empty();
        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
            $("#tabla tbody:last").append("<tr><td>"+item.id+"</td><td>"+item.name+
                    "</td><td>"+item.surname+"</td><td>"+item.surname1+"</td><td>"
                    +item.usertxt+"</td><td>"+item.password+"</td></tr>");
        });
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
});
}
```

This works fine, I have no problem...but I had to donwload an extension for Chrome to test locally, *Allow-Control-Allow-Origin*.

Why with GET method I have no problem and with POST method yes???

Greetings.

Comment: Are you calling to a service that i deployed in different machine?

Comment: @Joshi I`ve just updated the post.